# Delete file from a file set

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I have a following file structure:

```
/home/envs/ENV1
/home/envs/ENV2
...
/home/envs/ENVn
```

Inside each "ENVi" foled I have a "log" folder that collect log for application. I need to delete all logs for all envs periodically.

Is there any terminal command that I can do it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$ rm ~/envs/ENV*/log/*
```

Comment: and if the logs is in some subfolder? the ideia is something like:

/envs/**/logs/*.. something like that

Comment: It will be `rm ~/envs/ENV*/*/log/*`.